# How can I search for friends who live in a particular place?

Tags: facebook, google-plus

I'm going to be visiting a distant city in a few months, and want to start making plans with people I know there, some of whom I don't keep in touch with as regularly as perhaps one ought to. The major social networks have locations (and particularly, current residence) in peoples' profiles, but don't seem to have any search functionality coupled to that. When I search for a city on Google+, I find everyone I know who's ever lived there.

How can I do a search of "people I know living in city X"? I'm open to external utilities that hook into the sites' data, if that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Facebook, go to your profile/timeline and click on Friends, then use the drop-down list to choose "Search by Current City" and enter the name of the city.  This will find your Facebook friends that list that city as their current city.

You can also find people you may know who live in a particular city but are not currently your Facebook friends.  Click on Find Friends at the top of the window (not the one in the sidebar) and in the Current City field enter a city name.

If there is no "Current City" field, type a location and click the magnifier glass icon, or go to [this link](http://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=san%20diego&type=users).

**May 2013 Update:** Surprise!  Facebook has made some changes.

If you have Facebook [Graph Search](https://www.facebook.com/about/graphsearch), find your friends that live in a particular city by entering "My friends who live in *City*" in the Facebook search bar.  You can also enter "People who are not my friends and live in *City*" to find non-friends you may know or just "People who live in *City*" for both.

[image: Graph Search]

You can also find non-friends by going to your Timeline, click on **Friends**, then **Find Friends**, and enter the city under Current City.  Or use [this link](https://www.facebook.com/find-friends/browser/).

Comment: Cool, apparently Facebook added that since the last time I'd looked.

Comment: And now they have removed it. Down-voting the answer because it is no longer true. I know that is not the fault of the poster, but it seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: @BishopZ: Thanks, I've updated the answer for the latest Facebook.

Comment: That does not work mark4o. It is crazy but you can only look for non-friends in that way, i.e. people to add! Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these work anymore; thanks, Facebook.  And I can't post the new way to do this cuz I don't have 10 points yet; thanks, StackExchange.  XD  (upvote so i can post answer thx)

Comment: @GeoffreyHale Now you have 101 points. Please post your method.

Comment: As of Dec 2022, you can do this by typing "friends in [city] in the facebook search field. When you do this, the first section of search results will be titled "My friends who live in [city]." It'll show you the first few, followed by a link to see the rest.